# changing code from fs to fs-extra using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fs, fs-extra

I wrote a code by using `var fs= require("fs").promises;`

- to read all my files in directories and sub-directories

```js
var fs= require("fs").promises;

async function checkFileLoc(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return checkFileLoc(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files
    .reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), [])
    .filter((e) => e != null);
}
```

Then I install `fs-extra` package in my project and replace `var fs=require("fs");`to `var fse=require("fs-extra");` and made changes in my code like this

```js
var fse=require("fs-extra");

async function checkFileLoc(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = await fse.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fse.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return checkFileLoc(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files
    .reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), [])
    .filter((e) => e != null);
}
```

when I was using `fs` i was getting the desire output and someone told me `fs-extra` is advance then `fs` and all you have to do is replace `fs` with `fse`
my code not working properly any solution where i have made mistake ?

- My output while using `var fs= require("fs").promise;` is has i made to read all the files present inside directories

```
FilePath=
[/home/work/test/abc.html
/home/work/test/index.js
/home/work/test/product.js
]
```

- My output while using `var fse=require("fs-extra")` empty

```
filePath=[]
```

My output don't come while using `fs-extra`

Comment: "*someone told me fs-extra is advance*" - ask that someone then? I don't understand why you use fs-extra at all - you got a proper working code with native fs, why use an extra library?

Comment: as in project everything is written in `fs-extra` that's why need to change @Bergi

Comment: ok then, but how exactly is the code "*not working properly*"?

Comment: code working properly by using `fs` but need to change my code from `fs` to`fs-extra`

Comment: What *exactly* is going wrong? Error message? Please provide sample input & wrong output and expected output... etc.

Comment: Hello @trincot i updated my question and provided the Output which come while using `fs` and `fs-extra` I only have to read all my files using `fs-extra` method

Comment: Well, I took your above (working) snippet and replaced `var fs = require('fs').promises` with `var fs = require('fs-extra')` and it produced the same output both times

Comment: I made some changes now its working fine I have posted code in ans if you need you can review it :) and thank you for your time :)

Comment: Why would you even need "fs-extra" for this piece of code? Yes, "fs-extra" has some nice additional functionality, especially the support for promises was a nice feature before nodejs v10. But with recent versions of node and for this particular usecase it does not provide any advantages over the builtin fs  module from nodejs.

Comment: @derpirscher Apparently (deleted comments) their team lead asked them to use it, for consistent usage across the whole project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to figure it out what changes i have to made if I am using `var fse= require("fs-extra");`

so my code will look like this

```js
var fse=require("fs-extra");

async function checkFileLoc(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = fse.readdirSync(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = fse.statSync(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return checkFileLoc(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files
    .reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), [])
    .filter((e) => e != null);
}
```

I replaced my

- `var fs=require("fs");` to `var fse=require("fs-extra");`
- `let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);` with `let files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);`
- `const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);` with `const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);`

now i am getting my desire output

Comment: Your code is now blocking - statSync will not yield to the event loop and nothing will run concurrently.

Comment: so do i need to change anything @BenjaminGruenbaum ? if any changes required can you help me

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sorry first i used to await them but now i dont used await check my qstn code and ans code they are different :)